# Will the cloned fields in my form be identifiable when submitted?

Tags: jquery, clone

In my questionnaire I have a section for my clients to build a character profile for the different types of customers they cater to.  I used this snippet of JQUERY to achieve the cloning.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#newcus01").click(function(){
    $("#clone_div01").clone("*").appendTo("#page20").after("#clone_div01");
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle of the page I'm applying this to.
https://jsfiddle.net/6djnv9u2/7/

My concern is what's going to show up when the data is submitted?  Is each instance of cloning going to be distinguished in a way that can be identified or is it going to be a mess of information I'm going to have to double back to the original to figure out which answers belong to which questions?

Comment: have you tried submitting ? Also, IMHO that's not the right way to meet the requirements.

Comment: What is the `*` argument to `.clone()`? It takes a boolean that indicates whether it should copy event handlers and data to the clone.

Comment: If you clone a DIV with an ID, you're creating duplicate IDs. You should give the clone a new, unique ID.

Comment: the * argument is there from when I was trying to get it to clone all, forgot that was still in there lol

Answer (score 2):

All the fields in the cloned DIVs will have the same names. The server will not be able to distinguish them at all.

You should give the input fields names that end with `[]`. The server will then collect all the inputs with the same `name="something[]"` name into an array. You can then loop over the arrays to get all the corresponding inputs.

Note that checkboxes would have to be treated slightly differently, because the browser only sends the boxes that are checked, and the indexes won't be synchronized with other types of input. But your form doesn't have any checkboxes, so it's not an issue for you in this case.

Comment: yeah I was worried about the radio boxes because in other parts of the form, which isn't included here, I do indeed have them and have noticed that problem when I applied it to them.

Comment: Radio boxes should be OK, as long as you always have one of the choices selected. Only checkboxes are a problem.

Comment: ok.  As far as what you mentioned with the "[]" brackets, can those be added to IDs as well?

Comment: No, they're not needed in IDs, because the ID isn't sent to the server. IDs have to be really unique.

Comment: ok, as far as the names, I used the Questions as the names so I'd know exactly what the answers are referring to, but I have spaces in between the words, should I add an underscore to eliminate spaces or would that make a difference?

Comment: Whether you need to do that probably depends on the language you're using on the server. In PHP you access input parameters using strings, so any character is OK. But those long names will be a pain, e.g. `$_POST["Describe this type of Customer’s way of life."]`

Comment: ok thanks, I was planning on using javascript if possible, if I have further questions I'll post another, thanks for your help!!!